# Styled components not supporting octet literals

Tags: javascript, styled-components

Following piece of code doesn't seem to be working with styled-components

```
const currencyMap = {
    inr: ' \\20B9 ',
};

export const CurrencyIcon = styled.span`
    &:after {
        content: ${props => currencyMap[props.currency]};
    }
`;
```

where as if it is changed to following it is working perfectly fine.

```
export const CurrencyIcon = styled.span`
    &:after {
        content: ' \\20B9 ';
    }
`;
```

Has anybody faced similar issue and has workaround this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

styled-component converts the text inside template string as it is. If you look carefully, content css property is provided as string. So your template string should also have quotes, styled-component won't add quotes while generating css. Something like this

```
export const CurrencyIcon = styled.span`
    &:after {
        content: '${props => currencyMap[props.currency]}';
    }
`;
```

While all other css properties have literal values, content can have different types of values, string being one of them. https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/content